# Mock a stdout stream for bufio.NewScanner

Tags: testing, go, io, mocking, stdout

I want to write a test for a utility function where I use `bufio.NewScanner` and `Scan()`. I usually use it on `stdout` and now I want to simulate a short piece of stream where I can return some static string for the purpose of the test.

`bufio.NewScanner(r io.Reader)` takes a `Reader` but that only requires a `read` method. By reading the source code I couldn't figure out from which buffer it reads or how that gets passed in.

How can I mock that in a short and concise way?

Comment: What do you mean by using a `bufio.NewScanner` on `stdout`? Are you creating a new scanner using `stdout`?

Comment: @abhink yes `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdout)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simply test your code you can use @Sven's answer.

To get an idea of a simple `io.Reader` for testing, consider below example:

```
type R struct {
    Data string
    done bool
}

func (r *R) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    copy(p, []byte(r.Data))
    if r.done {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    r.done = true
    return len([]byte(r.Data)), nil
}
```

`R` is a custom test type that's implementing an `io.Reader` interface by having a `Read` method. Thus, it will be accepted by `NewScanner`. It can be used as:

```
func NewR(data string) *R {
    return &R{data, false}
}

r := NewR("Test\nmessage\n")
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)

for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("Line: %s\n", scanner.Text())
}
```

Output:

```
Line: Test 
Line: message
```

Both the type `R` and its `Read` method have been defined to work as a simple source of bytes. `Scan` calls its reader's (input to `NewScanner`) `Read` method until it gets an `EOF` or an error. For simplicity, `R`'s `Read` method copies its data to caller's buffer (`p`) in its first call and returns an `EOF` for any subsequent calls.

Note that actual splitting of the lines at `\n` is done by `scanner.Scan` and not `r.Read`.

You can modify the `Read` method above to get custom behavior as per your requirements.

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/zqDoQDIE93

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, that makes a whole lot of sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bytes.Buffer` since it implements the `io.Reader` functions.

**Example** https://play.golang.org/p/gjjMmT3SzD:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("foo\nbar")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(buf)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```